# Plotting monthly line plot crossing years pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
# setup data
data = {'April': {'1983': 1.19, '1988': -0.19, '1995': 0.41, '1998': 0.9, '2005': 0.35, '2007': -0.22, '2010': 0.48, '2016': 0.99, '2020': 0.45},
        'August': {'1983': -0.04, '1988': -0.99, '1995': -0.61, '1998': -1.25, '2005': -0.1, '2007': -0.77, '2010': -1.44, '2016': -0.63, '2020': -0.6},
        'December': {'1983': -0.94, '1988': -1.83, '1995': -1.0, '1998': -1.64, '2005': -0.97, '2007': -1.63, '2010': -1.65, '2016': -0.55, '2020': None},
        'February': {'1983': 1.94, '1988': 0.37, '1995': 0.71, '1998': 2.03, '2005': 0.46, '2007': 0.23, '2010': 1.35, '2016': 2.34, '2020': 0.46},
        'January': {'1983': 2.32, '1988': 0.99, '1995': 0.98, '1998': 2.37, '2005': 0.76, '2007': 0.8, '2010': 1.61, '2016': 2.66, '2020': 0.69},
        'July': {'1983': 0.17, '1988': -1.45, '1995': -0.11, '1998': -0.86, '2005': -0.19, '2007': -0.55, '2010': -1.04, '2016': -0.44, '2020': -0.27},
        'June': {'1983': 0.82, '1988': -1.44, '1995': -0.01, '1998': -0.24, '2005': 0.12, '2007': -0.28, '2010': -0.61, '2016': 0.05, '2020': -0.27},
        'March': {'1983': 1.49, '1988': 0.25, '1995': 0.48, '1998': 1.38, '2005': 0.53, '2007': -0.09, '2010': 0.98, '2016': 1.7, '2020': 0.56},
        'May': {'1983': 1.18, '1988': -1.0, '1995': 0.02, '1998': 0.7, '2005': 0.39, '2007': -0.38, '2010': -0.13, '2016': 0.39, '2020': -0.19},
        'November': {'1983': -1.1, '1988': -1.85, '1995': -1.1, '1998': -1.38, '2005': -0.64, '2007': -1.58, '2010': -1.69, '2016': -0.8, '2020': None},
        'October': {'1983': -0.96, '1988': -1.71, '1995': -0.92, '1998': -1.41, '2005': -0.1, '2007': -1.43, '2010': -1.73, '2016': -0.78, '2020': None},
        'September': {'1983': -0.36, '1988': -0.87, '1995': -0.9, '1998': -1.26, '2005': -0.11, '2007': -1.19, '2010': -1.67, '2016': -0.65, '2020': None}}
data_T = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 'index')

           1983  1988  1995  1998  2005  2007  2010  2016  2020
April      1.19 -0.19  0.41  0.90  0.35 -0.22  0.48  0.99  0.45
August    -0.04 -0.99 -0.61 -1.25 -0.10 -0.77 -1.44 -0.63 -0.60
December  -0.94 -1.83 -1.00 -1.64 -0.97 -1.63 -1.65 -0.55   NaN
February   1.94  0.37  0.71  2.03  0.46  0.23  1.35  2.34  0.46
January    2.32  0.99  0.98  2.37  0.76  0.80  1.61  2.66  0.69
July       0.17 -1.45 -0.11 -0.86 -0.19 -0.55 -1.04 -0.44 -0.27
June       0.82 -1.44 -0.01 -0.24  0.12 -0.28 -0.61  0.05 -0.27
March      1.49  0.25  0.48  1.38  0.53 -0.09  0.98  1.70  0.56
May        1.18 -1.00  0.02  0.70  0.39 -0.38 -0.13  0.39 -0.19
November  -1.10 -1.85 -1.10 -1.38 -0.64 -1.58 -1.69 -0.80   NaN
October   -0.96 -1.71 -0.92 -1.41 -0.10 -1.43 -1.73 -0.78   NaN
September -0.36 -0.87 -0.90 -1.26 -0.11 -1.19 -1.67 -0.65   NaN
```

The plot I create plots each year as a line plot, with the x axis being the month.

Now I want to plot the next 3 months of the following year (Jan, Feb, March) as a continuous line that goes to the right. I have the values stored in a similar dataframe.

```py
data1 = {'February': {'1984': -0.18, '1989': -1.37, '1996': -0.85, '1999': -1.31, '2006': -0.57, '2008': -1.56, '2011': -1.0, '2017': 0.02},
         'January': {'1984': -0.69, '1989': -1.87, '1996': -0.86, '1999': -1.69, '2006': -0.81, '2008': -1.58, '2011': -1.44, '2017': -0.33},
         'March': {'1984': -0.39, '1989': -1.05, '1996': -0.56, '1999': -0.9, '2006': -0.62, '2008': -1.12, '2011': -0.83, '2017': 0.12}}
data_T2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, 'index')

          1984  1989  1996  1999  2006  2008  2011  2017
February -0.18 -1.37 -0.85 -1.31 -0.57 -1.56 -1.00  0.02
January  -0.69 -1.87 -0.86 -1.69 -0.81 -1.58 -1.44 -0.33
March    -0.39 -1.05 -0.56 -0.90 -0.62 -1.12 -0.83  0.12


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))


data_T.reindex(['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September',
                'October', 'November', 'December']).plot(ax=ax,marker='o', color=['lightcoral','sienna','yellow','chartreuse',
                                                                             'turquoise','dodgerblue','fuchsia','purple', 'black'])
data_T2.reindex(['January','February','March']).plot(ax=ax,marker='o', color=['lightcoral','sienna','yellow','chartreuse',
                                                                             'turquoise','dodgerblue','fuchsia','purple'])
for line in ax.get_lines():
    if line._label == '2020':
        line.set_linewidth(4)
        line.set_marker('o')
ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=-1)
ax.set_ylabel("SST Anomaly (C)", weight='bold', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Month", weight='bold', fontsize=12)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
ax.set_title('Nino 3.4 SST Anomaly for Years Entering La Nina', fontsize=16, weight='bold')
```

When I plot these two together, it plots the second df back on the left hand side of the plot since the x-axis names are similar. How do I get the plot to continue to the right as one continuous line? Current plot for further clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can either plot by year or you can plot by months

  - If you plot by years, all the lines will be end to end, not stacked.
- I think the better option is to plot the adjacent years in a subplot
- Specify `ylim` the same for both plots, for scaling.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import calendar

# create the dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 'index')
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, 'index')

# get list of months and month abbreviations
months = list(calendar.month_name)[1:]
months_abr = list(calendar.month_abbr)[1:]

# color list
colors = ['lightcoral','sienna','yellow','chartreuse', 'turquoise','dodgerblue','fuchsia','purple', 'black']

# use the months list to order the dataframe rows
df = df.reindex(months)
df1 = df1.reindex(months[:3])

# setup figure and plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(17, 8))
df.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', color=colors, ylim=(-2, 3))
df1.plot(ax=ax2, marker='o', color=colors, ylim=(-2, 3))

# set the custom x-ticks; from matplotlib 3.5
ax1.set_xticks(range(12), months_abr)
ax2.set_xticks(range(12), months_abr)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

- If you get `UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator`, this is a pandas issue that will apparently be resolved in v1.2.x.

```py
# prior to matplotlib 3.5, set the xticks and then the xticklabels
ax1.set_xticks(range(12))
ax1.set_xticklabels(months_abr)
ax2.set_xticks(range(12))
ax2.set_xticklabels(months_abr)
```